# Android Fragments Clear Backstack without going back to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there any way to clear my fragment backstack. I tried this :

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

but it goes to the previous fragment

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: // in my case I get the support fragment manager, it should work with the native one too
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
 // this will clear the back stack and displays no animation on the screen
 fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: create method in activity and call in to fragment

Comment: @ExceptionLover It doesnt work instead it throws an exception E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions